# Send MVC model property with Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-grid

I want to send the model from this View to the `additionalData()` function so that I can send it to a method in a controller.

```
@model IEnumerable<ModelLayer.Models.TableNotificationModel>
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Kendo.Mvc
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<script>
    window.rootUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';
</script>
<h1>Upload index</h1>


<div>
    <h4>Upload file</h4>
    <form asp-controller="Upload" asp-action="Upload"
        enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <button type="submit" id="uploadBtn">Upload</button>
    </form>

    @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Message)');
        });
        </script>
    }
</div>


<div class="clearfix">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ModelLayer.Models.TableNotificationModel>()
        .Name("notificationGrid")
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable.Input(true).Numeric(false))
        .Scrollable()
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .ColumnMenu()

        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.OPERATOR_OBJECTID).Title("ID").Hidden();
            columns.Bound(c => c.SETTLEMENT_CODE).Title("settlement code").Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(c => c.TECHNOLOGY_CODE).Title("tech code").Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(c => c.UPLOAD_SPEED_CLASS_CODE).Title("upload").Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(c => c.DOWNLOAD_SPEED_CLASS_CODE).Title("download").Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(c => c.DATA_CATEGORY_QOS_CODE).Title("data category").Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(c => c.SHAPE).Title("shape").Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Message).Title("message").Width("100px");
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
            .Read(read => read.Action("Upload_Read", "Upload").Data("additionalData"))
            )
    )

</div>
<script>
    function additionalData() {
        return {
            operatorId: "@Model.operator"
        }
    }
</script>
```

but I see that it's now correct this way, it's not working. How can I access the `Model` from the JS function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Mixing Razor with JavaScript. That's one way to do it, as you have already done.

```
function additionalData() {
    return {
        operatorId: "@Model.operator"
    }
}
```

Assuming `Model.operator` is a string, keep in mind that you will have to escape quotes if your string can contain quotes. Also, currently if `operator` is `null`, you'll get an empty string (`""`) in JavaScript, which might not be what you want. Here's a more robust way of doing things:

```
operatorId: @(Html.Raw(Model.operator != null ? '"' + HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.operator) + '"' : "null"))
```

As you can tell, this is getting ugly really fast.

Option 2: JSON. A better way would be to convert your model to JSON using a serializer. Assuming JSON.NET is your serializer of choice, you could do this:

```
function additionalData() {
    return @(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
}
```

(Side-note: You can even configure the serializer to use the built-in `JavaScriptDateTimeUtcConverter` in order to convert `DateTime`s from .NET to `Date`s from JavaScript.)

The drawback of this approach is that this will expose your C# view model to clients, so it should never contain sensitive data.

Comment: where do I get the `value` from? :)

`JsonSerializerSettings` also throws an error saying:
JsonSerializerSettings is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Oops, that should've said `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)`. You can optionally pass a second parameter that's an instance of `JsonSerializerSettings` to configure the serializer, but the defaults work fine in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below:-

```
var displayedData = $("#notificationGrid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.view()
```

displayedData variable will contain the data which has been bound to the grid